# Access Java Web application running on a server by Android device thru wifi

Tags: android, web-applications, wifi, android-wifi, dynamic-ip

I have searched for a solution to this but could not find one. If this is already answered, sorry, please direct me to that.

My problem is this. I have java web application running on a local intranet (Tomcat 7, Java 6, MySQL). All desktops within the intranet are connected thru LAN and access the application using the specific server IP, something like 198.162.2.10.

Now, I want to access this thru my android mobile phone as well. The entire building is Wifi enabled and I'm able to access this web application, if I know the IP and enter it in the mobile browser. But, I would like to make this mobile access automatic and wrap it in an app which on click access this automatically, **even when the IP changes**. We have dynamic IPs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) component to display a web page within your application. 
As alternative you can use [HttpURLConnection](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) co perform Http request and posts to your web application.

Regarding the dynamic IP you can configure a Local dns server or assign a static IP to the server.
Anyway the application need a fixed address to connect to the web application, unless you want to insert the address manually each time.